# Overload resource-limit-setting in artemis for a user-id validated dynamically by the server

Tags: activemq-artemis

I do not want to store user information in the artemis server as my authentication will be KDF based. So, user will be dynamically validated based on some key from the client. Once verified I want to set the `max-connections` and `max-queues` for a user based on some role.

**broker.xml**:

```xml
<resource-limit-settings>
   <resource-limit-setting match="myUser">
      <max-connections>5</max-connections>
      <max-queues>3</max-queues>
   </resource-limit-setting>
</resource-limit-settings>
```

How can I pass UserId("myUser") at runtime so that resource limit setting can be set for each authenticated user ?

From the [Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/resource-limits.html):

> Unlike the match from address-setting, this match does not use any wild-card syntax. It's a simple 1:1 mapping of the limits to a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you quoted sums it up. You can't set limits based on a role. You can only set limits based on the user. Each user you wish to set limits for must be enumerated in `broker.xml`. Unlike other settings (e.g. `address-settings`, `security-settings`, etc.) there is no management API for resource-limits so they can't be added/removed/changed at runtime.

Of course, the functionality here can be enhanced. ActiveMQ Artemis is an open-source, Apache project and contributions are always welcome.

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. Any suggestion/thought on the functionality changes so that user I’d can be update at runtime to set the resource limit configuration ? Also, if I use Configuration class from Artemis API, does the changes will be updated to the broker dynamically ?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your question. Hope that clarifies!